# Genexus error src0216 in database impact analysis

Tags: genexus

I have a couple of transactions with a sublevel in Genexus, in which it stores some images and relevant related data.

When I press Build All and undergoes through the Database Impact Analysis, when it gets to that particular table it gives me an 'error src0216' message ( error: src0216: 'Firma' invalid property. (Line: 1, Char: 9) ) and there's no field called Firma anywhere (except in some descriptions).

I check the genexus wiki and it only describes a web panel error but not in the case of a table.

Any ideas about a case like this?

Thanks!

PS: I'm using Genexus 17 U6

Comment: Check whether you have any formulas that reference `Firma` in your table. Also check the `Initial Value` property on any new attribute from that table,

Comment: Thank you, very much! It was the answer to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to gusbro's answer, the problem was due to an `Initial Value` that was referencing to a Domain with an `Enum Value` that didn't exist anymore.